# Deploy angular application in apache folder

Tags: angular, apache

I have Apache server which is running Angular 6 application under `/var/www/html/<angular_root>`. I tried to add one folder `/var/www/html/admin/<angular_root>` but I get errors `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Do you know what configuration I need to implement?

My current apache configuration is:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/admin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you setting the correct base Href in your angular index.html file?

Comment: @MikeOne and @sancelot have correctly diagnosed the issue. By default, `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html`, and since you are using `admin` directory, you should have used base ref as '/admin' instead of default '/' at the time of compilation. You can later change it within generated `index.html` if you wish. @DmitryK has used `DocumentRoot` same as path of directory to host Angular code, so default base ref is working fine.

Comment: I have written a article about the same angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404 , hope this helps you  : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my working example:

```
<VirtualHost fancy.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "/abs/path/to/fancy/dist/browser"
    ServerName fancy.local
    <Directory "/abs/path/to/fancy/dist/browser">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `dist/browser` is a generated sources with `index.html`

Comment: As a side note, since you only host Angular code, `Options` should not be defined with "Indexes", "FollowSymLinks", "Includes" and "ExecCGI" for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Your angular project(s base href is wrong.
when you deploy your application, specify base-href on the cmdline :

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

for reference https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 3):

You need to add rewrite rules to .htaccess. Otherwise the requests to your routes won't be redirected back to index.html for rendering. 
Look at the following link for 
Apache deployment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my project which was on `tomcat` server, I have done the following:

1. Create a new folder inside `src/WEB-INF`.
2. Inside `WEB-INF` folder create `web.xml` with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

1. Update your `angular.json` build > assets section, when you build your project it will get copied to final `./dist` folder.

```
"assets": [
              {
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets/"
              },
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/WEB-INF"
    ],
```

4. Update your `index.html` file   `<base href="./">`

Hope this will helps someone.